# How to display custom comment type in wp-admin Comments section?

Tags: wordpress

I have a project with custom theme that has several custom comment types for different parts of the site and we want as administrators to moderate it.

I tried using the `parse_comment_query` and `comments_pre_query` filters but it didn't work.

here is my code:

```
add_action('parse_comment_query', function ($query) {
    if( is_admin() ) {
        $query->query_vars['type__in']=['review', 'comment'];
    }
    
}, PHP_INT_MAX, 1);


add_filter('comments_pre_query', function ($comment_data, $query) {
    if( is_admin() ) {
        $query->query_vars['type__in']=['review', 'comment'];
    }
    return $comment_data;
}, PHP_INT_MAX, 2);
```

For now, I only see the comment type `comment`, but I'm looking for other types as well, such as `review`, `vote`, etc.